# Code: 403. Errors: permission denied - while making API call to Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm following **Vault Configuration** example referring from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/. I've started server using windows machine.

```
vault server --dev --dev-root-token-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

two environment variables to point the Vault CLI to the Vault endpoint and provide an authentication token.

```
set VAULT_TOKEN="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
set VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

I am getting below error:

```
C:\Softwares\vault_1.0.1_windows_amd64>vault write secret/gs-vault-config example.username=demouser example.password=demopassword
Error writing data to secret/gs-vault-config: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/gs-vault-config
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the simply use `set VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

There is change in creating **key-value** in `Hashicorp Vault` now. Use `kv put` instead of `write`.

```
>vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config example.username=demouser example.password=demopassword
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2018-12-26T14:25:07.5400739Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1

>vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config/cloud example.username=clouduser example.password=cloudpassword
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2018-12-26T14:25:53.0980305Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In windows,

***Step1:***

```
set the VAULT_TOKEN & VAULT_ADDR

SET VAULT_TOKEN=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

SET VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

***Step 2:*** put the secret key & password using kv put

```
vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config example.username=hello example.password=world
```

Comment: It still says permission denied, I followed both of your steps

Comment: you need to run  `vault login`